# Code wont start

Tags: python-3.x

I don't understand why it wont start as yesterday the program ran very smoothly. I have tried everything restarting my computer, reinstalling python and debugging nothing has worked could someone please help me also i have tried to use the code in parts and still has not worked is it the code or python?

Thank you.

```
import os
import time
def main():


   print("Search: Registration | Login")
   print("Note: Must Registrate first to continue")
   time.sleep(2)
   print("Welcome To CityRP Gaming!")
   search = input("Search.... ")

   if search == 'registration':
      reg()

   if search == 'login':
     login()

    #Must Register to continue
def reg():


    print("Display Name")
    reg_user = input()
    print("Password")
    reg_pass = input()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Registration Successful!")
    main()    
    #Must Login to continue

def loging():


    print("Enter Username: ")
    username = input()
    print("Enter Password: ")
    password = input()

   if username == 'reg_user' and password == 'reg_pass':
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Login Successful!")
      logged()

  else:
      print("Try Again!")
      loging()

    #Main logged in interface
def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Welcome To CityRP Gaming")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("What would you like to do?")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Friends, Rules, Search, Register, Exit")
    cmdlist = input()

    if cmdlist == 'Friends':
        friends = input("Do you want friends?")
        logged()
    elif cmdlist == 'Rules':
        print('''\nRules:
    \n-No racism,
    \n-No mini-hitlers''')
        logged()
    elif cdmlist == 'Search':
        main()

   elif cdmlist == 'Register':
       reg()
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "it wont start"? Does python give errors or does the code just not run? And how are you trying to run it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the function you want to execute first.
For example: call `main()` at the end of your program - if you want  the main function to be executed.

Since python does not support [forward referencing](https://www.quora.com/What-is-forward-reference), you may want to place the main function at the end of your program.

Here is a working code

```
import os
import time
#Must Register to continue
def reg():
    print("Display Name")
    reg_user = input()
    print("Password")
    reg_pass = input()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Registration Successful!")
    main()    
    #Must Login to continue

def login():


    print("Enter Username: ")
    username = input()
    print("Enter Password: ")
    password = input()

    if username == 'reg_user' and password == 'reg_pass':
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Login Successful!")
      logged()

    else:
      print("Try Again!")
      login()

    #Main logged in interface
def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Welcome To CityRP Gaming")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("What would you like to do?")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Friends, Rules, Search, Register, Exit")
    cmdlist = input()

    if cmdlist == 'Friends':
        friends = input("Do you want friends?")
        logged()
    elif cmdlist == 'Rules':
        print('''\nRules:
    \n-No racism,
    \n-No mini-hitlers''')
        logged()
    elif cdmlist == 'Search':
        main()

    elif cdmlist == 'Register':
       reg()

def main():
   print("Search: Registration | Login")
   print("Note: Must Registrate first to continue")
   time.sleep(2)
   print("Welcome To CityRP Gaming!")
   search = input("Search.... ")

   if search == 'registration':
      reg()

   if search == 'login':
     login()

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: It works now but now login dose not work when i reg and then try login it dose not work?

Comment: no when i type the correct password it says its incorrect

Comment: Search: Registration | Login
Note: Must Registrate first to continue
Welcome To CityRP Gaming!
Search.... registration
Display Name
Mat
Password
mat
Registration Successful!
Search: Registration | Login
Note: Must Registrate first to continue
Welcome To CityRP Gaming!
Search.... login
Enter Username: 
Mat
Enter Password: 
mat
Try Again!
Enter Username:

Comment: The code seems to  be using `reg_user` as the default username and `reg_pass` as the password. This works when I execute the code added in the answer.
There is no implementation for custom username (Mat in your case) and password (mat) in your code.

If you need custom username and password implementation you will have to change the implementation

Comment: Yes but i want the password to be user input

Answer (score 0):

You clearly have a long way to go before CityRP Gaming is ready to be rolled out.
Here's your code with a few spelling mistakes taken out and the user and password stored in `global` variables (to get you going). You won't need them once you start storing them in a file/database etc.

```
import os
import time
def main():
   print("Search: Registration | Login")
   print("Note: Must Registrate first to continue")
   time.sleep(2)
   print("Welcome To CityRP Gaming!")
   search = input("Search.... ")

   if search == 'registration':
      reg()

   if search == 'login':
     login()

    #Must Register to continue
def reg():
    global reg_user, reg_pass
    print("Display Name")
    reg_user = input()
    print("Password")
    reg_pass = input()
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Registration Successful!")
    main()
    #Must Login to continue

def login():


    print("Enter Username: ")
    username = input()
    print("Enter Password: ")
    password = input()
    if username == reg_user and password == reg_pass:
      time.sleep(1)
      print("Login Successful!")
      logged()
    else:
      print("Try Again!")
      login()

    #Main logged in interface
def logged():
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Welcome To CityRP Gaming")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("What would you like to do?")
    time.sleep(3)
    print("Friends, Rules, Search, Register, Exit")
    cmdlist = input()

    if cmdlist == 'Friends':
        friends = input("Do you want friends?")
        logged()
    elif cmdlist == 'Rules':
        print('''\nRules:
    \n-No racism,
    \n-No mini-hitlers''')
        logged()
    elif cmdlist == 'Search':
        main()

    elif cmdlist == 'Register':
       reg()

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

p.s. not sure that `registrate` is a real word :)